# TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object. using API nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to get list of transactions from Gdax API ([link][1]): Here is the documentation for the method:

```js
var accountID = '7d0f7d8e-dd34-4d9c-a846-06f431c381ba';
authedClient.getAccountHistory(accountID, callback);
// For pagination, you can include extra page arguments
authedClient.getAccountHistory(accountID, {'before': 3000}, callback);
```

I believe the issue is in the callback, but I don't understand how to fix it.

Here is my implementation:

```js
self.getTransactions = function(options, callback) {

  var key = options.key;
  var b64secret = options.secret;
  var passphrase = options.passphrase;

  var Gdax = require('gdax');
  var authedClient = new Gdax.AuthenticatedClient(
    key, b64secret, passphrase);

  var accountID = '32fb94c4-cda2-52f1-9bae-1866a0605789';
  authedClient.getAccountHistory(accountID, function(err, response, transactions) {
    let details;
    details = {
      timestamp: util.timestampNow(),
      error: err.message,
      data: []
    };
    if (err || resp.statusCode !== 200) {
      let error = err || new Error(`Error ${resp.statusCode}: ${resp.body}`);
      result.error = error.message;
      return callback(error, result);
    }
    _.each(transactions, function(transaction) {
      let data = {
        transaction_id: transaction.id,
        total: transaction.amount,
        type: transaction.type
      };
      details.data.push(data);
    });
    callback(null, details);
  });

};
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: "How can I resolve this error?" --- simply don't pass something that is not "a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object". `callback(err, transactions);` --- here `transactions` is `undefined`.

Comment: thank you. I changed it to `callback(err, details);` However, I am still receiving the same error

Comment: And `details` is not even defined. You need to invoke a `callback` from within a `authedClient.getAccountHistory` callback.

Comment: I have edited the code a bit. Is details still `undefined`?

Comment: thank you, gives me a good place to start